# Facebook like button displaying wrong title in the facebook profile wall

Tags: button, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps

We have built a website in wordpress and have implemented social share icons (Twitter/FB like/G+/...) using the AddThis plugin.

When I FB like an article, the article is displayed in my FB profile wall but with wrong title (e.g instead of displaying `example.com` in my wall it's displaying `example sample blog`)

I have checked the meta tag `fb:app_id` and id is correct.

I have used debug tool to check the meta tag are read properly by FB and is correct.
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Found no help in FB forum or in google.

Appreciate urgent help.

Thanks in advance.